# checking each element in 2 dimensional list

Tags: python, list

basic question:

i am trying to check each element in this 2d list

```
board = [['B', 'B', 'B', ' '],['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],['B', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
```

if at least one element == `' '`

then I want to have my function return True 
otherwise if they were all not `' '` then return False.

this is what I have so far but it stops at the first iteration of the loops thinking the first element inside the string is B then will return False without ever getting to the 4th element of the first list.

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    for i in range(len(b[1])):
        if b[i][i] == ' ':
            return True

        else:
            return False
```

Comment: you shouldn't use i as the index in both of your loops

Comment: Also, unless your indenting is different, you return True or False with the first element checked and stop iterating

Answer (score 5):

Use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
any(' ' in b for b in board)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> board = [['B', 'B', 'B', ' '],['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],['B', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
>>> any(' ' in b for b in board)
True
>>> any(' ' in b for b in board[1:])
False
```

The `in` operator can be used to check whether an item is present in an iterable or not, and it is very fast compared to a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code try ...

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(len(b[i])):
        if b[i][j] == ' ':
            return True
return False
```